# Saving specific key/value pair to user class in Firebase using Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, swift2

I'm attempting to save a user thumbnail image as a base64 string to the appropriate logged in user object on Firebase like so:

```
if self.myRootRef.authData != nil {
    let profileId = self.myRootRef.authData.uid
    let myThumbnail = self.profileImage.image!.resizeToWidth(75.0)
    let imageData:NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myThumbnail, 0.7)!
    self.base64String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
    let fString = ["profileThumbnail": self.base64String]

    self.userRef.childByAppendingPath(profileId).setValue(fString)
}
```

But unfortunately, it keeps removing the other keys. I have a feeling I'm doing this wrong. How would I save this to an already existing object (even if the profileThumbnail key doesn't exist on the object) without removing all other key value pairs?

Comment: It's not clear with 'removing the other keys means'. I tested the code (without the image encoding code) and it works fine and does not remove other keys within the /users node

Comment: Maybe by 'keys' you mean other children within the /users/uid/ node? If so, then yes, setting the value of the /users/uid/ node you are essentially overwriting everything in that node. You should add one more level /users/uid/profileThumbnail, and then setValue to that child node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to Jay's solution is to use [`updateChildValues`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/saving-data.html#section-update):

```
if self.myRootRef.authData != nil {
    let profileId = self.myRootRef.authData.uid
    let myThumbnail = self.profileImage.image!.resizeToWidth(75.0)
    let imageData:NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myThumbnail, 0.7)!
    self.base64String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
    let fString = ["profileThumbnail": self.base64String]

    self.userRef.childByAppendingPath(profileId).updateChildValues(fString)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need another level in the update so you are not overwriting the entire node. There are several ways to accomplish this but here's an option.

```
if self.myRootRef.authData != nil {

      let profileId = self.myRootRef.authData.uid
      let myThumbnail = self.profileImage.image!.resizeToWidth(75.0)
      let imageData:NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myThumbnail, 0.7)!
      self.base64String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
      //you may NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters in options
      let fString = blah blah

      let thisUserRef = self.userRef.childByAppendingPath(profileId)
      let thisUserProfileRef = thisUserRef.childByAppendingPath("profileThumbnail")
      thisUserProfileRef.setValue(fString)

}
```